# Convert .pro lines in Qt to cmake lines

Tags: qt, cmake

I need to convert two lines from .pro file in Qt to corresponding lines in CMake:

CONFIG -= staticlib

CONFIG += shared

what should I write in cmakelist file to generate teh same effect as this ?

.pro file :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-10-10T11:50:45
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += testlib network concurrent xml
QT       -= gui
QT += xmlpatterns

DEFINES += CID_SDK_LIBRARY
CONFIG -= staticlib
CONFIG += shared

CONFIG(debug,debug|release) {
  message(Compiled in Debug)
  debug:   DESTDIR = debug
} else {
  message( Compiled in Release )
  release: DESTDIR = release
}

OBJECTS_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.obj
MOC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.moc
RCC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.qrc

TARGET = lib/cid-sdk
TEMPLATE = lib
#CONFIG += staticlib c++11
CONFIG += sharedlib c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

#TEMPLATE = subdirs
#SUBDIRS += \
#    tests\UnitTests    # an "app" project


#UnitTests.depends = Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Sdk Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Sdk.Core Nl.Aet.Cid.Sdk.Desktop.Gateway

include(Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Deps\Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Deps.pri)
include(Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Sdk.Core\Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Sdk.Core.pri)
include(Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Sdk\Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Sdk.pri)
#include(Nl.Aet.Cid.Enabler\Nl.Aet.Cid.Enabler.pri)

##Desktop API
include(Nl.Aet.Cid.Sdk.Desktop.Gateway\Nl.Aet.Cid.Sdk.Desktop.Gateway.pri)
include(Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Sdk.Desktop\Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Sdk.Desktop.pri)

#Web API
include(Nl.Aet.Cid.Sdk.Web.Gateway\Nl.Aet.Cid.Sdk.Web.Gateway.pri)
include(Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Sdk.Web\Nl.Aet.Cid.Client.Sdk.Web.pri)

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

note : I edited it to add the .pro file as requested.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no 1:1 translation of those lines, which affect deeply the build process and in a way that would change several different points of CMakeLists.txt. Post the whole .pro and we can se how it can be translated.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I added the .pro file as requested.

Comment: @user3602386 for example there is no method to add .pri to cmake for obvious reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In qmake every .pro file yields a "module" in your project structure. The module has a product. This product might be an executable/application, static library, or a dynamic/shared library.

CMake on the other hand does not do this implicitly. To add module one would normally use the [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_library.html) function.

To mimic this particular behavior you would write either

```
project("my_library")
set(sources <your source files go here>)
add_library("my_library" STATIC ${sources})
```

or

```
project("my_library")
set(sources <your source files go here>)
add_library("my_library" SHARED ${sources})
```

Now the problem here is that we're missing the list of `sources`. In your case they are defined in the .pri files.